# Matplotlib & Tkinter integration

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

Trying to display a Matplotlib plot that gets updated in real-time inside a Tkinker Module however I error with the Application freezing and not allowing me to click on any buttons and displaying the updated plot.

Code:

```
def data_points():
    f = open("data.txt", "w")
    for i in range(10):
        f.write(str(randint(0, 10)) + '\n')
    f.close()

    f = open("data.txt", "r")
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    l = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        l.append(int(data[i].rstrip("\n")))
    return l

class Graph(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_window()

        self.init_widgets()

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.title.set_text('ECG Monitoring')
        self.ax.set_xlabel("Time [mS]")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude [V/mV]")
        self.ax.grid()

        self.graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill='both', expand=True)

    def init_window(self):
        self.title('DIY-ECG Graph')
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.iconbitmap('./imports/msoe.ico')
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def init_widgets(self):
        # reference to the master widget, which is the tk window
        self.pause = tk.Button(self, text="Pause", command=self.button_handler,
                               bg="red", fg="black")
        self.start = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.button_handler,
                               bg="green", fg="black")
        self.Screenshot = tk.Button(self, text="ScreenShot", command=self.screen_shot,
                                    bg="blue", fg="white")

        # creating top frame for left and right side of the buttons
        self.start.pack(side='top', fill='x')

        self.pause.pack(side='top', fill='x')

        # information of the heart rhyming in the future this will controlled by an AI
        self.rhythm = tk.Label(self, text='Rhythm - Normal Sinus').pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.heart_label = tk.Label(self, text='HR: 100').pack(fill='x')
        self.PR_label = tk.Label(self, text='PR: 0.12').pack(fill='x')
        self.QRS_label = tk.Label(self, text='QRS: 0.12').pack(fill='x')
        self.QT_label = tk.Label(self, text='QT: 0.32').pack(fill='x')

        self.Screenshot.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.continuePlotting = False
        self.pause['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.start['state'] = 'normal'

    def button_handler(self):
        self.change_state()
        threading.Thread(target=self.plotter(), daemon=True).start()

    def change_state(self):
        if self.continuePlotting:
            self.continuePlotting = False
            self.pause['state'] = 'disabled'
            self.start['state'] = 'normal'
        else:
            self.continuePlotting = True
            self.start['state'] = 'disabled'
            self.pause['state'] = 'normal'

    def plotter(self):
        print("inside plotter")
        while self.continuePlotting:
            print("inside plotter(s) while statement")
            self.ax.cla()
            self.ax.grid()
            self.dpts = data_points()
            self.ax.plot(range(10), self.dpts, marker='o', color='orange')
            self.graph.draw()
            time.sleep(1)

    @staticmethod
    def screen_shot():
        print("inside screenshot")
```

When the user selected a button on another GUI the graphing class will start allowing you to call it. The graphing class gets called by a different class named window which is a Tkinter frame.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI.App()
    # creation of an instance
    GUI.Window(app)
    GUI.MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=self.plotter(), daemon=True).start()` will execute `self.plotter()` *immediately* in main thread instead.  It should be `threading.Thread(target=self.plotter, daemon=True).start()` instead.

Comment: Yepp that seemed to fix the problem. I was also able to fix other issues I had with multithreading with tkinter. Thanks!